# How to generically update a case class field using LabelledGeneric?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Using shapeless, one can use `LabelledGeneric` to update case class fields like so:

```
case class Test(id: Option[Long], name: String)
val test = Test(None, "Name")
val gen = LabelledGeneric[Test]

scala> gen.from(gen.to(test) + ('id ->> Option(1L)))
res0: Test = Test(Some(1),Name)
```

I would like the `Test` class (and others) to extend an abstract class `Model`, that will implement a method `withId` that would use a `LabelledGeneric` similar to the above code to update the `id` field, should it have one (which it should).

My attempt adds an implicit parameter of a `LabelledGeneric[A]` to the constructor of `Model`, which materializes just fine. I also need to somehow provide evidence to the record syntax that the `LabelledGeneric#Repr` has the `id` field to replace. Adding an implicit `Updater` parameter to `withId` satisfies the compiler, so that the code below will compile, but it is not usable.

```
import shapeless._, record._, ops.record._, labelled._, syntax.singleton._, tag._

abstract class Model[A](implicit gen: LabelledGeneric[A] { type Repr <: HList }) { this: A =>

    def id: Option[Long]

    val idWitness = Witness("id")

    type F = FieldType[Symbol with Tagged[idWitness.T], Option[Long]]

    def withId(id: Long)(implicit u: Updater.Aux[gen.Repr, F, gen.Repr]) =
        gen.from(gen.to(this) + ('id ->> Option(id)))

}

case class Test(id: Option[Long], name: String) extends Model[Test]
```

When calling `test.withId(1)`, the implicit `Updater` fails to materialize. The macro reports that `gen.Repr` isn't an `HList` type, when it in fact is. It seems that [this match](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/e8926d163adc7015403c8296b22ed71827c585a0/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/generic.scala#L494-L496) is the one that fails, where `u baseType HConsSym` returns `<notype>`. Equivalent to:

```
scala> weakTypeOf[test.gen.Repr].baseType(weakTypeOf[::[_, _]].typeConstructor.typeSymbol)
res12: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = <notype>
```

This is using shapeless 2.3, though it fails for different reasons in 2.2 (seems as though `Updater` had a large refactor).

Is it possible to accomplish this with shapeless, or am I way off target?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue here is that the refined result type of the LabelledGeneric (`Repr`) is lost. At `Model`, the only thing known about `Repr` is `Repr <: HList`. The implicit `Updater.Aux[gen.Repr, F, gen.Repr]` searches for something that is only known as `_ <: HList` and thus fails to materialize.
You'd have to define `Model` with two type parameters
`abstract class Model[A, L <: HList](implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, L])`
but this doesn't allow you to write `class Test extends Model[Test]` and you have to write the labelled generic type by hand.

If you instead move the `gen` down to `withId`, you can make it work:

```
object Model {
  private type IdField = Symbol with Tagged[Witness.`"id"`.T]
  private val  IdField = field[IdField]

  type F = FieldType[IdField, Option[Long]]
}
abstract class Model[A] { this: A =>
  import Model._

  def id: Option[Long]

  def withId[L <: HList](id: Long)(implicit   // L captures the fully refined `Repr`
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, L],           // <- in here ^
    upd: Updater.Aux[L, F, L]                 // And can be used for the Updater
  ): A = {
    val idf = IdField(Option(id))
    gen.from(upd(gen.to(this), idf))
  }
}

case class Test(id: Option[Long], name: String) extends Model[Test]
```

If you're concerned with resolution performance, you can cache the value(s) in the companion of `Test`:

```
case class Test(id: Option[Long], name: String) extends Model[Test]
object Test {
  implicit val gen = LabelledGeneric[Test]
}
```

This would mean that code like this

```
val test = Test(None, "Name")
println("test.withId(12) = " + test.withId(12))
println("test.withId(12).withId(42) = " + test.withId(12).withId(42))
```

would use the definition of `Test.gen` instead of materializing a new `LabelledGeneric` every time.

This works for both, shapeless 2.2.x and 2.3.x.